# How do I get JSON Objects into my ListView Fragment?

Tags: android, json, android-listview

I'm stepping my way thru gathering data off a mySQL server, converting it to JSON via PHP, getting the JSON asynchronously using AQuery, converting the result to a string/object, but now how do I get the strings to my lisview items and display it in my list fragment activity?

( PS: I know the JSON data is there via the Log.i() and there is no JSONException error caught)

Thnx for your input

W/in my Main Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    Fragment vC = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.viewContainer);
    Fragment lC = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.listContainer);
    if (vC == null)
    {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.viewContainer, new WebViewFragment());
    ft.commit();
    }
    if (lC == null)
    {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.add(R.id.listContainer, new NavigationListFragment());
    ft.commit();
    }
...
```

List Frag Activity:

```
public class NavigationListFragment extends ListFragment
{
    Context context;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    AsyncTasks.getJSONArray(context);// asynchronous task for getting JSON array
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
    {
    // TODO
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // TODO
    }

    static int q_id;
    static String label;
    static String title;
    static String description;
    static String gotoURL;

    public static void jsonListCallback(JSONArray json)
    {
    try
    {
    Log.i("NavigationListFragment", json.toString());

    // Parse the string to a JSON object
    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
    {
    JSONObject json_data = json.getJSONObject(i);
    q_id = json_data.getInt("_id");
    label = json_data.getString("label");
    title = json_data.getString("title");
    description = json_data.getString("description");
    gotoURL = json_data.getString("gotoURL");
    }
    } catch (JSONException e)
    {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview, container, false);

    return view;
    }
}
```

AsyncTasks Class:

```
public class AsyncTasks
{
    public static void getJSONArrays(final Context c)
    {
    // initialize
    final AQuery aq = new AQuery(c);

    String url = "http://192.168.1.11/Andaero/php/regulatory_list.php";
    // long expire = -1; TODO
    aq.ajax(url, JSONArray.class, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>()
    {
        public void callback(String url, JSONArray json, AjaxStatus status)
        {
        if (json != null)
        {
        NavigationListFragment.jsonListCallback(json);// Send the JSON
                                  // Array back to
                                  // the list
                                  // fragment
                                  // activity
        }
        switch (status.getCode())
        {
            case AjaxStatus.TRANSFORM_ERROR:
            Log.i("GetJSONArray", "TRANSFORM_ERROR");
            break;
            case AjaxStatus.NETWORK_ERROR:
            Log.i("GetJSONArray", "NETWORK_ERROR");
            // TODO Create Alert Dialog
            case AjaxStatus.AUTH_ERROR:
            Log.i("GetJSONArray", "AUTH_ERROR");
            break;
        }
        }
    });
    }
}
```

My Listview XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#003399"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:layoutAnimation="@anim/layout_animation_row_left_slide" />

</LinearLayout>
```

List Item XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/acItem"
    style="@style/listItem" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listLabel"
        style="@style/listAcronym" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTitle"
        style="@style/listTitle" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listDiscription"
        style="@style/listDiscription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dummy"
        style="@style/listDiscription" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dateAdded"
        style="@style/listDates" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `FragmentManager` to find your fragment (by id or tag), cast it to `NavigationListFragment` and invoke a (non-static) method on it to set the JSON object.

Assuming `Fragment lC = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.listContainer);` is the fragment you are referring to, you can simply do:

```
NavigationListFragment navListFragment = (NavigationListFragment)lC;
navListFragment.someNonStaticMethod();
```

Comment: how would I  **invoke a (non-static) method on it to set the JSON object.** ?  Plz see my edit - added the main activity onCreate. thnx